# Difference between du -sh */ and du -hd 1

Tags: linux, filesystems, du

I tried to find out how big each directory in my root-directory is.
I cd'ed to / and did:

```
ls | xargs du -sh
```

the result:

```
...
1.9M    tmp
975M    usr
70G     var
...
```

Then I went to /var/www and did:

```
du -sh
```

the result:

```
81G     .
```

I am intrigued: How can a folder inside a 70 GB  folder be 81 GB?

After experimenting a bit, i found out that:

```
du -sh /*/
```

will result in

```
...
1.9M    tmp
975M    usr
70G     var
...
```

whereas du -hd 1 will result in

```
...
1.9M    tmp
975M    usr
91G     var
...
```

Two different sizes for the /var directory, but all other directories have no difference in size.

What's the difference between those two variations of the du command?

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't tell this is the case for sure (because you didn't provide full `du` outputs) but `du` keeps track of inodes it visits, so if there are hardlinks then only the first occurrence will be counted.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for that bit of information, i didn't know that yet. But all other directories have the exact same size in both methods. Only /var differs. If it'd be the inodes, shouldn't it equal out in sum?

Comment: As far as I can tell the equivalent to `du -h -s $something` is `du -h -d 0 $something`. With `-d 1` I don't see the same items listed. Also, with either option, inode are only taken in account once; several hardlinks don't inflate the reported size.